# Modified magento extension to use wysiwyg editor, now text won't save

Tags: sql, magento, magento-1.6, php

I recently modified a Magento video extension so that one of the fields used the WYSIWYG editor, instead of just being plain text, but now nothing entered saves.

The field was originally called 'content' so I had to change that to 'description' so that everything displayed properly, and made sure I changed 'content' to 'description' everywhere I  thought I'd need to (where the property is called in the design/..../template/ folder, where the property is created in the form).

The WYSIWYG editor now displays correctly, but it has wiped all the original descriptions, and  won't let me save any more (if I type a new description and press 'save', when I go back to the settings for the video, the description is not there.

I don't think any of the remaining instances of the word 'content' in the extension are related to the property, as they appear in pairs (e.g. two files, one videocontroller.php, one videocategorycontroller.php, both used in the same way, but the 'video category' pages never used 'content' in the same way as the video pages).

The only other file I thought could have sorted it was the SQL installation file which contained:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('video')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('video')} (
`video_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`video_category_ids` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`description` text NOT NULL default '',
`status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
`created_time` datetime NULL,
`update_time` datetime NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;");

$installer->endSetup();
```

where 'description' has already been changed from 'content', but changing this and uploading it made no difference.  There is an sql upgrade file, do I need to make a new sql upgrade file?

Apart from that I'm stumped, any thoughts?

Edit: Saveaction as requested

```
public function saveAction() {
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        if (isset($data['video_category_ids']))
            $data['video_category_ids'] = implode(',', $data['video_category_ids']);

        $data['filename'] = Mage::helper('videoblog')->trimYouTubeUrlFormat($data['filename']);

        $model = Mage::getModel('video/video');
        $model->setData($data)
                ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

        try {
            if ($model->getCreatedTime == NULL || $model->getUpdateTime() == NULL) {
                $model->setCreatedTime(now())
                        ->setUpdateTime(now());
            } else {
                $model->setUpdateTime(now());
            }

            $model->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Video was successfully saved'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
                return;
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Unable to find video to save'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

edit: code\community\Aurora\Videoblog\Block\Adminhtml\Video\Edit\form.php:

class Aurora_Videoblog_Block_Adminhtml_Video_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

```
protected function _prepareForm() {
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
        'method' => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
            )
    );

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

protected function _prepareLayout() {
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled()) {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);
    }
    }
}
```

code\community\Aurora\Videoblog\Block\Adminhtml\Video\Edit\Tabs\form.php:

```
class Aurora_Videoblog_Block_Adminhtml_Video_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

protected function _prepareForm() {
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('video_form', array('legend' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Video')));

    $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Title'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'title',
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('filename', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Video'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'filename',
        'after_element_html' => '<small style="color: red;display: block">'.Mage::helper('videoblog')->__("Youtube video id after 'v=' (e.g. ear2SunyaZE)").'</small>',
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('video_category_ids', 'multiselect', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Category'),
        'name' => 'video_category_ids',
        'required' => true,
        'value' => '1',
        'values' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->getCategory(),
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Status'),
        'name' => 'status',
        'values' => array(
            array(
                'value' => 1,
                'label' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Enabled'),
            ),
            array(
                'value' => 2,
                'label' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Disabled'),
            ),
        ),
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('description', 'editor', array(
        'name' => 'description',
        'label' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Description'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Description'),
        'style' => 'width:500px; height:200px;',
        'config'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(),
        'wysiwyg' => true,
        'required' => true,
    ));

    if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getVideoData()) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getVideoData());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setVideoData(null);
    } elseif (Mage::registry('video_data')) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('video_data')->getData());
    }
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the saveAction in `Company/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/nameController.php

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: Did you clear cache after you change the db field name (regardless if magento cache is disabled)? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/749/new-column-added-to-table-not-saving

Comment: yep, flushed the cache, still not saving after adding the new field

Comment: In `saveAction` do Mage::log(data); or print_r(data); is the field there?

Comment: no, do they need to be?  They weren't there before I started modifying the extension and the original descriptions saved just fine :\

Answer (score 0):

you only need to change the '**label**' of content field in form.php file

so you description field look like

```
$fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
    'name' => 'content',
    'label' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Description'),
    'title' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Description'),
    'style' => 'width:500px; height:200px;',
    'config'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(),
    'wysiwyg' => true,
    'required' => true,
));
```

even though if you dont want to used the field of content then you can create new field in database using below script.

create script **mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php** //if your module version 0.1.0 (to 0.1.1 update version in script file)

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
 ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('video')} ADD   description varchar(255) NULL ;

");

$installer->endSetup();
```

open your **etc/config.xml** and change the version to **0.1.1** save file.

hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this triggers the issue I had in the first place, causing this to happen:  http://i.imgur.com/xnBoHso.png

Comment: what error you got? n which solution you implemented created new feild or just change the label?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, just changing the label creates the issue in the image I posted on my reply - all other fields are added to the wysiwyg text box.  I've just created the update file and ftp'd it to the server, will that take effect immediately or is there something else I need to do?  currently it still isn't saving text

Comment: there are 2 form.php files so I've posted both

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'check updated fieldset', I have added the sql update and refreshed the cache but it's still not saving

Comment: i mean only update this in form php $fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
    'name' => 'content',
    'label' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Description'),
    'title' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Description'),
    'style' => 'width:500px; height:200px;',
    'config'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(),
    'wysiwyg' => true,
    'required' => true,
));

Comment: Hey again, as I said in my second reply, just changing the Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Description'), 'title' => Mage::helper('videoblog')->__('Description') causes the issue in this image i.imgur.com/xnBoHso.png

Comment: its not about label it should $fieldset->addField('content' instead of description.
 getting??

Comment: Changing $fieldset->addField('description'  back to $fieldset->addField('content'  creates the issue in the image I posted

Comment: strange!!!!!!!! your table content description and content feild both ? if not then which one filed exist in table? (not in script)

Comment: the original field in the table was 'content', but it meant I couldn't use WYSIWYG, so I had to change the field to description (and now there should be a 'description' field in the table)

Comment: then it should $fieldset->addField('description' as you did. where you change in feild name? in script or directly in database?

Comment: That's what it is, but it still doesn't let me save the text